# How to pass conditional variabiles to Laravel Blade Component

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade component for password fields and this is how I pass my information:

```
<x-store.password-field
     label="Password"
     name="password"
     placeholder="••••••••"
     error="Error message"
/>
```

As you can see, I have a variabile called `error` in order to display an error message if available. Now, I know how to display it in the page:

```
@error('password')
    {{ $message }}
@enderror
```

Is there a way to add this logic directly in the component so it should be something like `if $error then add error="$message"` to the component? **The example below will not** work but it's just for illustration to show you what I mean:

```
<x-store.password-field
     label="Password"
     name="password"
     placeholder="••••••••"
     @error('password') error="{{ $message }}" @enderror
/>
```

Comment: Does [this info](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/access-at-error-inside-a-blade-component) help? ... seems close to what you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going too much into details I wold like to describe who Laravel validation works. So this way I believe everything makes more sense.
So when Laravel validates a form based on the rules you have set, it knows what kind of data it is expecting and if there are invalid data provided an ValidationException will be thrown. This

> Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException.php

class has all these methods and properties. But I will mention the errorBag property that holds the error messages. So the exception obj($e) have access to all the error messages. If you do not take the responsibility to handle this exception, Laravel will do the handling as well. There is an

> Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php

class and you can see how it is handled in details. But shortly this is where the exception is converted to http response, by default it redirects back, and there are two other method called withInput and withErrors. Both of these flash the data to the request session. So this way form input data and error messages are stored in the session and they can be retrieved anywhere from the application. As you may know retrieving data from the session can be performed using session() helper or Session facade or any other way. But for convenience Laravel provides helper method **old()** and in the other hand shares the **$errors** attribute to all the views. So **old()** is used to retrieve old from input data and **$errors** is an

> Illuminate\Support\MessageBag.php

obj that provides some useful methods to retrieve validation errors. Well **$errors** is shared to all the views something we would do inside the AppServiceProvider like `View::share('errors', session()->get('errors'));` but instead of ServiceProvider Laravel has done it using middleware:

> Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession

. And that's because no matter if there are errors or not you don't have to test if **$errors** isSet etc.

Inside of any view file the **$errors** attribute is available as well as the **old()** method. So it's all set for you to use. Anyway how you decide to retrieve data from the session is is your choice, but since there are all these things provided as well as Laravel blade instead of:

```
<?php
  if($errors){
?>
 //do something
<?php
  }
?>

// Blade offers:
@if($errors->has('password'))
  //do something
@endif

// Or even more cleaner like:
@error('password')
  //do something
@enderror
```

Since **$errors** or MessageBag instance is shared to all the views, I don't think you would ever want to pass it like a prop. And that because you can access it directly from the component.

However if you want to send it as a component prop you could do it. But don't forget the **$errors** is a MessageBag object. As well every single input field can have more than one error message for example name can contain both **'Min length is two characters'** and **'Name should contain only letters'**. For this reason `$errors->get('name')` will return an array. Since **$errors** is an MessageBag instance there are useful methods like `$errors->first('name');` that will return the first element on the array and that is the error message, in this case **'Min length is two characters'**. I want to mention that the error messages may not be identically to the one Laravel provides. But just to show the point. So in your case try something like this:

```
<x-store.password-field
     label="Password"
     name="password"
     placeholder="••••••••"
     :error="$errors->first('password')"
/>
```

Notice that when the data you want to provide is not just a simple string, you should add **:** in front of the attribute name. Otherwise the content it will be considered as a string.

Comment: This is the most amazing answer I ever received on StackOverflow. Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad you liked it

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is take a look inside your blade input component (components/input.blade.php). There you should be able to condition the variable $error with session.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).